# Porque mi login no me esta redirigiendo!

Tags: php, pdo, login

Cuando ingreso ,e redirige a la pagina donde esta el archivo controlador

que es esta

> http://localhost/index/Login/controlador/login.php

ESTE ES EL ARCHIVO MODELO:

```
<?php

class conexion{

private $conexion;
private $host = "localhost";
private $usu = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $db = "gimnasio";

public function __construct(){

    $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->host, $this->usu, $this->pass, 
 $this->db);

    if($this->conexion->connect_errno){
        die("error no se conecto con mysql:(".$this->conexion-
>connect_errno.")");
    }
}

public function cerrar(){
    $this->conexion->close();
}

public function login($login, $pass){
    try {
        $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
        $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));

        $base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=gimnasio" , "root", "");
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM personas WHERE idPersonas= :login";

        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->execute(array(":login"=>$login));

        while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            #echo "Usuario: " . $registro['idPersonas'] . " Contraseña: " .$registro['Nombres'] . "<br>";# 
            if($registro['roles_idRoles'] == 1){ 
                header("Location:../vista/interfaz_admi_nueva.php");
            } else {
                header('Location:/index/Usuario/index.php');
            }
        }

        $resultado->closeCursor();


    } catch(Exception $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }   
}
}
?>
```

> ESTE ES EL ARCHIVO AL QUE ME REDIRIGE CUANDO SE DEBE REDIRIGIR A LA INTERFAZ DEL USUARIO O ADMINISTRADOR

```
<?php

include("../modelo/conexion.php");

$user = isset($_POST['idPersonas']);
$pass = isset($_POST['Contrasena']);

$gimnasio = new conexion;
$gimnasio->login($user, $pass);
$gimnasio->cerrar();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludos, tu problema se encuentra en la validación del rol:

```
if($_SESSION['roles_idRoles'] == 1){
}
```

ya que estas usando una variable superglobal  para hacer esta misma cuando el que te tiene ese resultado es $registro, por lo tanto debería ser de esta manera:

```
while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        #echo "Usuario: " . $registro['idPersonas'] . " Contraseña: " .$registro['Nombres'] . "<br>";# 
        if($registro['roles_idRoles'] == 1){ 
            header("Location:../vista/interfaz_admi_nueva.php");
        } else {
            header('Location:/index/Usuario/index.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SERGIO si esta respuesta te sirvió para resolver el problema, márcala como aceptada pulsado en el icono que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.